# Is there a way to mirror local and online MySQL databases?

Tags: mysql, localhost

While doing web work, I've found it the fastest to run WAMP and work locally -- which has unavoidably resulted in the follow question: Is it possible to mirror (or very easily duplicate/clone) MySQL databases?

The idea would be so I could work locally -- including database manipulation, and transfer all work online easily.

My apologies if this is a duplicate question -- I looked around on Stack Overflow and Google, but didn't really find anything.

Comment: i don't think it's possible....data replication is possible, but i guess that's not wht u r looking for..

Comment: @Ashwini - Not possible because of MySQL architecture, or a mechanism hasn't been developed yet?

Comment: there hasn't been a mechanism..it's possible to move the database using the tool called mysql migration toolkit...http://dev.mysql.com/doc/migration-toolkit/en/mysql-migration-toolkit-introduction.html may be this will help..

Comment: @Ashwini - you might as well post this as an answer ;)

Comment: Thanks Julian I have done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to move the database using the tool called [MySQL migration toolkit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/migration-toolkit/en/mysql-migration-toolkit-introduction.html), maybe this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you won't want to duplicate the production data on a non-production system; restoring it from a backup is normally sufficient.

However, you always want to duplicate the schema and other objects (stored procedures, views etc). This should not be a problem, as you will have scripted them entirely in your SCM repository, so you can just run the scripts on your test system, and you have an identical database structure to production.

If you have NOT scripted all your database objects, then you can't expect the test system to be useful; you need to ensure that all database schema is maintained as part of the app, in your SCM so that developers can make changes in a controlled way.

Comment: I'm just looking to develop locally, and then easily transfer all data to my web host... it doesn't have to be automatic--is there a simple MySQL export/import?